# Checking PCB Layout, Routing Tips and Improvements?

Tags: pcb-design, power-electronics, high-voltage, kicad, routing

I've made some significant revisions to my old PCB design and wanted some advice on routing! This time I've tried to properly space the large current/voltage traces, kept traces short where possible, and also minimized VIA usage.

This is a power switching board that is designed to handle 30 VDC @ 5 A. It uses transistors for switching, and comparators for measuring the voltage difference between two batteries and then a voltage follower to get a low impedance output to drive raspberry pi GPIO pins. I've tuned R8/R9, R14/R15 to give 2-3V when input is 20-30V (Vrange of my battery). Pullup resistors are used since my comparators are open collector.

- Here are some of my questions: Can I run signals on the bottom layer
  even though I have a ground plane?
- I learned that VIAs have some inductance, does this mean that I should be
  spacing them far away from components, specifically capacitors?
- I have some high voltage, low current signals, but found it difficult to
  space them away from the other lower voltage traces to avoid crosstalk,
  any tips for optimizing for this?
- If I have a large voltage/current signal that on the front
  layer would crosstalk with multiple other traces, would it be better to
  use a VIA to transfer it to the bottom layer and back up again to avoid
  crosstalk?

Here's how the circuit works: When Vext is disconnected, Vint1/2's current flow to Q2 base, which provides a current path for the R1/R2 voltage divider to ground. R1/R2 bias the Q1 pmos to have a strong -Vgs (more negative than Vgsth), allowing current to flow to load. So Vint1/2 provide load voltage. When Vext is connected, R4/R5 bias the Q3 gate, redirecting current to GND. So Q2 no longer conducts and the current in R1/R2 doesn't have a ground path. The Vgs is now ~0V. Because it is now less negative than Vgsth, Q1 doesn't conduct. So Vext provides load voltage.

Thank you for your time.

[image]

[image]

Comment: The inductance of a via is typically irrelevant at the signal frequencies found in power switching circuits. Do you have a specific reason to be so concerned about it? My advice is start worrying about via inductance when your signal frequencies get above 500 MHz.

Comment: Nope, no particular reason, I'm just new to routing techniques, so am unfamiliar with how adding vias bear on the routing. Understood, I'll keep the 500MHz number in mind.

Comment: Are you actually using a ground plane on one side? It seems you are running some of the ground connections manually. If you use a ground plane most of the ground pins for THT parts will be automatic, and this may give room to simplify other top side traces. If you do flip sides to make a connection try keeping the ground plane side traces as short as practical, that will minimize chopping up the ground plane, (one example: The long trace from R6).

Comment: Understood, I'll try not to split up the grounding plane too much. I'm not sure what you mean by the manual ground connections. Yes i'm doing some grounding manually because i'm using smd components and so i treated each padded ground pin as a common ground node to pull from. Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: There's nothing stopping you from using 4 layer stackup even with through-hole. Then use both outer layers for signals and one of the middle ones for ground. As for vias and inductance/capacitance, that's mostly a concern in sensitive RF designs - this is not such a design.

Answer (score 1):

Your board is essentially working at DC.

Therefore:

1. You can run signals on bottom layer. As long as the plane is not too broken by routing other signals, it should work fine.
2. Vias do have inductance. So do PCB tracks, wires, cables, and everything else. The inductance does approximately nothing at DC. Vias also have resistance. So do PCB tracks, wires, cables, and everything else. So as long as the via (or group of parallel vias) is rated to handle the DC current without acting as a fuse and melting open, or dropping too much voltage due to resistance, vias are fine. Also, everything, such as vias, PCB traces, wires and cables have capacitance. It also does nothing at DC.
3. 30V is not high voltage and if it is DC, it can't cause crosstalk.
4. Large voltage signals don't crosstalk if they are slow enough. You can also keep more distance between important signals, or run a ground trace between two important signals.

Comment: Ahhh I see, I remember learning #2 in my microelectronics class, but I didn't make the connection until I read your comment. Thanks!

Right, so to avoid crosstalk, space important signals from each other and run the ground between them. Got it. What do you mean by "slow signals"? Low current? What are some examples of important signals?